# group.equal loadings - failure to compute standard error lavaan

Tags: r

I am running a multiple group analysis. Everything runs fine here:

```
fitcfa.inv3b <- cfa(cfa, data=smart, group = "gender", meanstructure = TRUE,
group.equal=c("loadings", "lv.variances"), group.partial = 
c("housing ~~ housing", "transp ~~ transp", "foodsec ~~ foodsec", 
"service ~~ service", "age ~~ age"))
```

but when I add "intercepts":

```
fitcfa.inv4 <- cfa(cfa, data=smart, group = "gender", meanstructure = TRUE,
group.equal=c("loadings", "lv.variances", "intercepts"), group.partial = 
c("housing ~~ housing", "transp ~~ transp", "foodsec ~~ foodsec", 
"service ~~ service", "age ~~ age"))
```

I get an error that the program cannot compute standard errors, and my model may be underidentified. I am sure this is not the case - I added df! - and am very confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell without the data. If model is not identifiable, I would say you have insufficient amount of data.

Comment: I would assume that adding df would never cause a model to go from identified to underidentified - which is why I find it so strange. I also have a massive N of over 900!